# ASP.Net Web Service on clientside "Soap header security was not understood"

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have created a web service in Visual Studio 2010 using the wsdl provided by our vendor. I have created an interface using their wsdl and implemented that interface for our implementation. They also need a SSL certificate so we have provided them certificate open ssl of windows. Web service also implements authentication using soap header.

But they are unable to connect and getting the following error

```
<soap:Body> 
  <soap:Fault> 
    <faultcode>soap:MustUnderstand</faultcode> 
    <faultstring>SOAP header Security was not understood.</faultstring> 
  </soap:Fault> 
 </soap:Body>
```

My web service code is as follows for your reference

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3;


namespace MyWebService1
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for PSWebService
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
    [WebServiceBinding(Name = "PSWebService", ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle = SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]

    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the  following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    public class PSWebService : Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol, IPartStoreRequiredServiceSOAP11Binding
    {
    public UserCredentials consumer;
    Functions objFunctions = new Functions ();
    String SqlConnStr = "Data Source=test\\test;uid=sa;pwd=abc123;database=testdb";

    public AeslPSWebService()
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(Binding = "PSWebService")]
    [SoapHeader("consumer", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In, Required = true)]
    public CustomerInformationOutput getCustomerInformation(CustomerInformationInput   custLookUpInput)
    {

        CustomerInformationOutput cio = new CustomerInformationOutput();

        try
        {
        if (checkUser())
        {
            // My business logic goes here
        }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }



    private bool checkUser()
    {
        // In this method you can check the username and password 
        // with your database or something
        // You could also encrypt the password for more security
        if (consumer != null)
        {
        if (consumer.Username == "sa" && consumer.Password == "abc123")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        }
        else
        return false;

    }




    }


    # region "SOAP Headers"

    public class UserCredentials : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
    {
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
    }

    # endregion

}
```

Please help as i am unable to resolve it.